# iPhone: "Locking" a Cell to the Top of TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to have a cell at the top of the table always remain there and not scroll down when an object is added i.e. the cell should stay at `indexpath.row==0`. Is it possible to lock a cell to a certain position in a table?
If so, how would this be implemented?

*EDIT*

If i made a different section for this cell that would work wouldnt it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't force a tableview cell to always remain on screen. That would defeat the purpose of having a table in the first place.

Instead, if you need something always displayed in a tableview, you put it in either a the table's header or footer views. Create the view you want and then assign it to the tableview's
`tableHeaderView` or `tableFooterView` property.

Comment: i believe this would work.
i would implement this as a property correct? 
and then create an array to add that cell to this header?

Comment: You create a UIView, either programmatically or in Interface Builder, with the textfields, buttons etc that you want to always display. Then assign that view to the `tableHeaderView`. That view is distinct from the table i.e. it is not a row of the table. You need to write custom code to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a table's header - check `tableHeaderView` property in UITableView

Comment: I think @Alx talks about freezing a cell in some position. So that it won't scroll together with the table. Something like the freeze option in Excel - usually used for headers...

Comment: The "to a certain position" part kind of makes me think that's not the case (locking a cell to the middle of the table would look... how?) but maybe you're right.

Comment: I am trying to have a cell at the top of the cell always remain there and not scroll down when an object is added .

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't possible because tableview is a in uiscrollview, maybe if you add the subView to your navigationController.view?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog](http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=100) post a useful trick to have static content at the top of a `UITableView` and allow it to react to touches.